# How to retrieve POST Request object/parameters in @ExceptionHandler method

Tags: spring, rest

I have a controllerAdvice/@ExceptionHandler method. I need to access my Request paramaters in my ExceptionHandler method.
I can retrieve URI with getRequestURI() but don't know how to retreive POST request parameters
I have some identifier parameters that I must send back with ExceptionResponse. How do I do that?

```
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public @ResponseBody MyResponse handleResourceNotFound(final HttpClientErrorException ex,
            final HttpServletRequest request) {
        String str = request.getRequestURI();
        System.out.println(str);
        MyResponse response = new MyResponse(ex.getResponseBodyAsString(), 0, "-1");
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward approach for this. In my case I did like the following.

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/test/")
@ResponseBody
public boolean isExist(@RequestBody Person person, HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.setAttribute("requestBody", person);
    int i = 1/0;
    return person != null && person.isExist();
}
```

**Exception handler**

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public @ResponseBody MyResponse handleResourceNotFound(final HttpClientErrorException ex,
        final HttpServletRequest request) {
    String str = request.getRequestURI();
    System.out.println(request.getAttribute("requestBody"));
    MyResponse response = new MyResponse(ex.getResponseBodyAsString(), 0, "-1");
    return response;
}
```